# Indexing not working for the list of similar elements i require through xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here I require to fetch the list of elements represented in class = 'i-dark-drill-down', as you can see in the HTML code with the Xpath i am referring to it gives me 5 similar elements. However, when i apply `index[1]` it still shows 5 elements and if I use index[2] then nothing at all displays.
So when I am traversing through this list one by one in a for loop then on second iteration for `index[2]`

[image: IMages for HTML]

noSuchElement exception comes..

xpath I am using is //*[contains(@id,'Canvas')]//*[name()='svg' and @id = 'defaultID']//*[@class='i-dark-drill-down']

Can somebody help me to figure out where I am wrong here ?
Thanks in advance !

Below is HTML Code

Comment: The image is unreadable, post the html and code as text.

Comment: @Guy : posted the HTML code and xpath I am using ,HTML code i shared here will show two occurrence of class="i-dark-drill-down" ... in actual there are five occurrence so I think 2 will be enough to help here

Comment: How are you using the index? post an example please. And the `xpath` you posted is not a valid `xpath`,  post the actual one.

Comment: Not sure why * not displayed in xpath.... let me try again Xpath =    //*[contains(@id,'Canvas')]//*[name()='svg' and @id = 'defaultID']//*[@class='i-dark-drill-down']

Comment: Without the full code I can't be sure, but it might be timing issue, try adding some [wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). You should also check if the element still exists in the DOM after the first iteration.

Comment: As a side note, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

@Prateek

to iterate over index with xpath you have to input round brackets example:

- Index 1

> (//div[@id='something'])[1]

- Index 2

> (//div[@id='something'])[2]

etc...

try to limit the search with xpath over the DOM with * extension. 
It will make the search slow and inefficient.

In your case if i understand properly, xpath should be something like

```
(//div[contains(@id, 'Canvas')]//div[@class='Btn3D']/div[@class='i-dark-drill-down'])[index number goes here]
```